# Error while using math.roundoff function in a textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, double, rounding

I want to round off the values in 2 textboxes, say `textbox1` and `textbox2` if Roundoff `menustrip` is checked and leave the value as it is if it is not checked. `textbox1` and `textbox2` carries the result of some calculation which will be always numeric. I used the following code but error occured while debugging that `"Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid."`

NB: `ReadOnly` property of the textbox is set to `True`

```
Private Sub mnuRoundOff_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuRoundOff.CheckedChanged
        Dim r, s As String
        Dim t, u As Decimal
        r = TextBox2.Text
        s = TextBox3.Text
        t = r * 1
        u = s * 1
        If mnuRoundOff.Checked = True Then
            TextBox2.Text = Math.Round(t, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
            TextBox3.Text = Math.Round(u, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
        Else
            TextBox2.Text = r
            TextBox3.Text = s
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: a textbox contains text, Math expects a number. hence the error

Comment: r and s will be number always.  And that's why I have multiplied each of their values with 1 to make it a number. Is that not right?

Comment: `Dim r, s As String` means r and s are always strings/text.  `u= r * 1` is giberish - turn on Option Strict

Comment: Did you actually read the error message?  It's telling explicitly that an empty string can't be converted to a `Double`.  You say that the `TextBox` will always contain a number but obviously that's not true.  The error message makes it clear that the `TextBox` is empty sometimes.